Is "the above table" more acceptable than "the below table", and if so, why?
I was reading a draft document and encountered a sentence along these lines:

The below table shows costs for three different options.

This phrasing feels weird to me; I'd be inclined to recast as "The table below..."
But this feels okay to me:

The above table shows costs for three different options.

Is there actually some linguistic distinction that makes "above table" more acceptable than "below table"? Or is this just my instincts misfiring?

In English, above and below go after table or a noun. That text is from a non-native speaker.

Must be that 'above' can work as adjective or adverb, but 'below' only as adverb. I see the below table all the time in IT drafts I edit. Once, autocorrected to bellowed table.

@YosefBaskin Now that you've reminded me to check instead of assuming: yes, according to at least one dictionary, "above" is recognised as an adjective but "below" is not. Guess it's time for a self-answer.

@Lambie "Above" can go either way - it's not uncommon to see references to things like "the above example".

"The below table/illustration/text" appears to be an artifact of the Indian dialect of English.

Probably a duplicate

This question is similar to: What's the difference between saying 'the passage above' or 'the above passage'? (itself closed as a duplicate of Which is correct ... 'the below information' or 'the information below'?). But the contrasting  views on acceptability ('the above table' / 'the below table') are not directlt addressed.

Also related: Why is the adjective "below" rare compared to adjective "above"?

I prefer "see the table, below...". I think of this as a short form of "see the table that is located in the text below this sentence." I would not write "see the below table" -- to my ears, it really doesn't work as an adjective. For that matter, I don't like "above table" either, I would always use "the table, above...." or "the preceding table..."

As an aside, it's probably better to number the tables and refer to them by their number. That way you don't need to change your sentences if you move the tables around.

Why is this tagged "prepositions"? Although both "above" and "below" can be prepositions, in this construction they are adjectives modifying "table". They have no prepositional object. And I'd say that either before or after "table" is correct.

This above/below thing is often found in legal and quasi-legal texts. And in them, they go after the noun.

@Wastrel ...I have no idea why I tagged it that way, apologies. Fixing tags.

Examples of below used as a pre-head modifier in a noun phrase are rarer than those of above, but are not unheard of, and apparently it is becoming more popular.

Sir, we have received in the office the below number of
signatures, petitioning for government support of Mr: Eric Heffer's
Bill for the Abolition of Hare Coursing as a result of a single
advertisement in each of the following newspapers (British Parliament, Bill Hansard, House
of Commons, 1967)
The commission assumes that the cost of U. S. engagement in
Afghanistan and Iraq will decrease significantly by 2020. The
below figure is based on a projected estimate of thirty thousand combined troops in both countries. (Richard Dorment, Esquire, 2010
Vol. 154, Iss. 4; pg. 156)
However, tickets have already sold out for the weekend so you may have
to get started to think about next year, if reading the below list is
filling you with envy. (Cal Byrne, Irish Mirror)
Universal Credit mainly takes into account one’s expenses and income to decide the rate they will receive. To claim, Britons must meet all of the below criteria (Liverpool Echo)

Hits in the News on the Web corpus for the last few years of 'the below NOUN'

2022 3114
2021 2640
2020 3400
2019 1632
2018 718
2017 912
2016 742

At least one dictionary has caught on with Merriam-Webster listing below as an adjective.

written or discussed lower on the same page or on a following page
the below list

Ngrams confirms this particular string's increasing popularity.


Yes, I'd say 'above' is established as a prenominal adjective (getting close to a determiner) and 'below' is undergoing a similar conversion.

Regardless of Ngrams, sometimes usage dictates whether to put "above" or "below" before or after the noun that it modifies. "The above sky and the below earth" will probably never gain popularity, even in academia.

On checking, the two words are not perfect antonyms: "above" is recognised as an adjective in the Cambridge Dictionary, but "below" is not.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/above

above adverb, adjective (ON PAGE)
When used in a piece of writing,
"above" means higher on the page, or on a previous page: Please send
the articles to the address given above. The letter was sent to the
above address.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/below
[no comparable entry here]

From Forum.Word Reference,com (selected comments):

The Columbia Guide to Standard American Usage says

There's nothing wrong with the above address, the statement above,
and the like, except perhaps for a bit of stiffness, especially when
repeated as formulas. But make sure that both adjectival and noun uses
are appropriate to the context, and be aware that Edited English
dislikes them for their imprecision.

The American Heritage Dictionary, which has a panel of people that it
considers to be experts on American style and usage, says [that even
the above figure is not accepted by all]:

The use of above as an adjective or noun in referring to a preceding
text is most common in business and legal writing. In general writing
its use as an adjective (the above figure) is accepted by a majority
of the Usage Panel, but its use as a noun (read the above) is
accepted by only a minority.

...
It may be correct in theory, but I doubt many native speakers would
write it. Google searches for the below picture and the picture
below turn up over 100 times as many hits for the latter as for the
former.  ... The below picture had 2.4 million Google hits. So the
below picture is widely used but less widely so than the picture
below.

I'd echo that 'the below N' is widely used, but less widely than 'the N below', but that the gap is narrower with 'the above N' and 'the N above'. But 'the above N' is seen as grammatical by many, 'the below N' by less Anglophones.
But 'the below N' is becoming more idiomatic. English in flux.
